# iPhone: Resizing UIImageView doesn't resize the 'touch area'

Tags: iphone, resize, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView.  In IB I attached a 'Touch Up' event on this UIImageView to call an IBAction in my code.  This all works fine.

In some cases I need to resize this UIImageView in my code.  I do this by settings it's 'frame' property.  The resizing works fine.  The problem is that the 'touch area' stayed the original size.

What I mean is that let's say I start with a UIImageView of 100x100:

```
***
***
***
```

Then resize it to 200x100:

```
***xxx
***xxx
***xxx
```

In this case the UIImageView shows up in the entire area (* and x) but the touches only respond in the original area (represented by *).

How can I also resize the area that responds to touch events?

**EDIT:**  I should also mention that I move the UIImageView's origin as well, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Are there other views (maybe transparent) in front of it?

Comment: Interesting; how did you manage to add a Touch Up event on UIImageView? Those should only be limited to subclasses of UIControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In IB I attached a 'Touch Up' event on this UIImageView to call an IBAction in my code. This all works fine.

Uhhh no it does not. Touch up events can only be sent to `UIControl` subclasses, which `UIImageView` is not.

So I think you are confused and you might have more views than you think. Have you maybe added a transparent button on top of your image that you forgot to resize?

Note that you can also use a `UIButton` with an image set if you need 'image button' behaviour.

Comment: Yeah you're right, silly mistake on my part.  There was a UIButton on top there.  Someone else had edited this in IB so I got confused.  I was naive to assume that all UIView subclasses could be interacted with.  Anyways, I'll mark this as accepted and burry my head in the ground.  Thanks.